# set decimal value for property in c# is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below i have public property in c#
Get is working. But set is not working.

```
private decimal _basketTotal;    
public decimal BasketTotal
{
   get
   {
     decimal total = PreDiscountTotal - DiscountTotal;
     if (total < 0)
     {
                return 0;
     }
     else
     {
        return total;
     }

   }
   set 
     {
        this._basketTotal = value;
     }
}
```

I tried this way to set the value for BasketTotal

```
Basket baskObj = WebSession.Basket as Basket;
baskObj.BasketTotal = (decimal)localTotal;
```

When i debug the above code. _basketTotal is got value. But BasketTotal is not getting the value.

Comment: To improve your "get" code take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx ;)

Comment: You have a getter which returns a calculated value (based on two other properties) and a setter which sets a value.  How should those interact?  I would think you only want a getter and no setter for this property.

Answer (score 3):

Your `get` isn't returning `_basketTotal`, so that value is never used.

In your `get`, you can see that you're never referring to `_basketTotal`, and you are instead recalculating it every time.

Try something like this instead

```
private decimal? _basketTotal;    
public decimal BasketTotal
{
    get
    {
        if(_basketTotal == null)
        {
            //recalculate the total
             decimal total = PreDiscountTotal - DiscountTotal;
             if (total < 0)
             {
                _basketTotal = 0;
             }
             else
             {
                _basketTotal = total;
             }
        }
        return (decimal)_basketTotal;
    }
    set 
    {
        this._basketTotal = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can get the value. But i am able to set new value to BasketTotal.

Comment: i'm guessing english isn't your first language, but I can't make sense of what you're saying. You're saying you can do something, but you can do something? Please elaborate how you want `_basketTotal` and `BasketTotal` to work.

Comment: Ok. Here i am explaining my problem.

BasketTotal is my mail property for saving my basket value. _basketTotal is private variable just to store the tmp to assign BasketTotal value. When i try to get obj.BasketTotal, I am able to get BasketTotal value. At the same time, When i am try to set the value for BasketTotal. I am unable to set.

obj.BasketTotal = 10;

10 is not set to BasketTotal. This is problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value in your property and then have your property return the same value you set, your getter needs to return the variable that your value gets set in. To oversimplify your property, it needs to resemble the below:

```
private decimal _basketTotal;    
public decimal BasketTotal
{
    get
    {
        return _basketTotal;
    }
    set 
    {
        this._basketTotal = value;
    }
}
```

If you need a default value, you can define it in your constructor or add some condition to your getter as shown in DLeh's answer.